# How to softcode the name of the worksheet in excel?

Tags: excel

If cell A1 contains 'sheet1', how can I use that fact to enter a formula in another cell that contains the value of cell B2 on sheet1?

If I hardcoded 'sheet1', I could just say ='sheet1'!B2

But how can I say something like =A1!B2 ?
or =sheet(A1)!B2 ?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Indirect formula to accomplish this: `=INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!B2")`

Comment: Just be aware that INDIRECT() is volatile and will cause all sheets in the workbook to re-calculate when ANY cell is changed. In small workbooks that may be fine, but in large data models, volatile formulas can be the cause of workbook slowness.

Comment: @teylyn Agreed. user1471465, you should try to find a different method of accomplishing a similar result if you will be doing this over many cells. Indirect formulas will quickly bog down a large workbook; see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx#sectionSection2 and http://chandoo.org/wp/2014/03/03/handle-volatile-functions-like-they-are-dynamite/ for more information.